# lazy loading return null value

Tags: spring, jpa, lazy-loading

i use spring 3.2, spring data and jpa.

i save an Advertisement object,
after i save message

i try to access message from Advertisement but it's null

```
@Entity
public class Advertisement implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="id", cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Message> messages;
}

@Entity
public class Message implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
private Advertisement advertisement;
}
```

test unit

```
Advertisement ads = new Advertisement();
ads = advertisementRepo.save(ads);

assertNotNull(ads);
assertNotNull(ads.getId());

Message message = new Message();
message.setAdvertisement(ads);
message = msgRepo.save(message);

ads = advertisementRepo.findOne(ads.getId());
ads.getMessages(); //return null
```

why ads.getMessages() don't return messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that bidirectional relationships are not transparently managed by JPA. When manipulating one side of a bidirectional relationship, the application has to ensure that the other side is updated accordingly.

This can easily be done by writing setter methods that update the associated entity as well. For example, when setting the `Advertisment` of a `Message`, you can add the `Message` instance to the collection in `Advertisment`:

```
@Entity
public class Message implements Serializable {

    ...

    public void setAdvertisement(Advertisement advertisement) {
        this.advertisement = advertisement;
        advertisement.getMessages().add(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: that work but in Advertisement, i need to do:  
Set<Message> messages = new HashSet<Message>();  
before i had:  Set<Message> messages;

Comment: Sure, you need to initialize the collection, I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to save the `Advertisement` after you assign it a new `Message` collection:

```
Advertisement ads = new Advertisement();
ads = advertisementRepo.save(ads);

assertNotNull(ads);
assertNotNull(ads.getId());

Message message = new Message();
message.setAdvertisement(ads);
ads.setMessages(new HashSet<Message>());
ads.getMessages().add(message);
ads = advertisementRepo.save(ads);
message = msgRepo.save(message);

ads = advertisementRepo.findOne(ads.getId());
ads.getMessages(); //return null
```

Answer (score 0):

This is returning null because you are saving the non-owning entity first and then the owning entity. If you save `message` before `ads` it should return non-null value.